# Phonegap iOS Notification Alert accept user input

Tags: ios, cordova

Is there a way where I can call a native notification on Phonegap iOS that accepts user input and retrieve the value?
Like this one:

[image: native alert]

Based from this http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html there are only two types of notifications - notification.alert and notification.confirm.

Any ideas are very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, [there is an old iphone plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/Prompt) in the official plugins repository.

If you're using Phonegap 2.0, you may need to make little changes to the code.